# How to get an interactive console when baking a plugin in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

*Using CakePHP 2.6.7*

When baking a normal part of an application (e.g. using `cake bake model`) the console is interactive - it goes through the construction process asking for you to choose options at each stage.

But when using `cake bake model MyModel --plugin MyPlugin` to do the same for a plugin no options are displayed and it generates the model in the plugin folder using default settings.

Is there a way to make the generation of the individual parts of a plugin interactive in the same manner? (this goes for model/controller/view)

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry! Added it now. Particularly important since version 3 is out now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a model in a plugin is baked using `cake bake model MyModel --plugin MyPlugin` it uses scaffolding. To avoid this you have to use `cake bake model --plugin MyPlugin` and then the first option presented will allow you to choose from the possible models to be baked.

Replace `model` with `controller`/`view` as appropriate to bake those as well.